# Can you crimp a tubular lug without a crimper plier?

Tags: electrical, tools, cables

I want to use [these lugs](http://www.intelli.com.br/_english/produto.php?apl=1&idi=56) on my electrical installation, but I can only find pliers for up to 16 mm<sup>2</sup> cables and the mains cables are 25 mm<sup>2</sup>. I found one store that carried pliers able to do up to 50 mm<sup>2</sup>, but they where VERY expensive (about 150 dollars).

Is it possible to use these nice lugs without proper pliers? (I will need to crimp at most 8 lugs).

Comment: is this going on 4 AWG wire?

Comment: Closer to 3 AWG.

Comment: is this a ground wire?  What is it's purpose?

Comment: These are supply wires (2 phases) coming from the meter to the breaker and from the breaker to que distribution panel. I realise that I don't need those lugs, but I wanted to use them just to make it more tidy.

Comment: Did you realize that in most every State in the USA, only a Master Electrician is allowed to connect conductors from a meter to a distribution panel.  Most utility companies will not turn on power unless a master has signed off on the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I know the wire in question is in a main distribution panel from the meter to the main lugs, any crimp must be done with the proper tool and dies. This will require maybe a ton of pressure and absolutely no shortcuts would be advised.  Also note that this type of work usually requires the sign off and supervision of a Master Electrician.  Check with your local electrical utility for inspection and sign off requirements.  Please be careful, this is potentially  extremely dangerous and a great risk of fire if not done properly.

Comment: I'm in Brazil. Those cables are the "setup" for a meter panel. The process is standardized and describe the cables and connections left in the meter panel and at the top of the pole. After that the eletric company verifies this setup, installs the meter and then connect the cables left on the top of the pole to the live mains line.

BTW: There is no such thing as a Master Electrician in Brazil. There are electricians that generally do a fair to poor job. If you want something according to the standard you have to DIY. Also, terminal lugs arent't needed on the standard I wanted to add them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a vice or possibly some metal bar clamps if you have them around?